# customizing the css for audio tag

Tags: css, audio

i have this audio control and i am trying to change even the color of the player but i can't target it i found some posts talking about doing this using javascript is that the only way to write css for it.

```
<audio controls class="radio-audio">
   <source src="" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

i tried to write some code like this found it somewhere on the internet but still i don't see any changes.

it is all hover and focus not doing much

```
.radio-audio:hover, .radio-audio:focus, .radio-audio:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.radio-audio {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px #006773;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px #006773;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0px #006773;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared you on `codepen.io` a model with all the css tags to access the graphics properties of an audio object

[link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LLJeRx)

Comment: thank you so much man it is really helpful but i what if i want to change the play btn color. I see i can just change the background color only 
https://codepen.io/heshamelmasry77/pen/pwOayb

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to style HTML5  players using CSS. Instead, you can turn off the `control` attribute, and implement your own controls using JS. If you don't want to do it yourself, you can use something like [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org).